# Trying to rename certain file types within recursive directories

Tags: bash, macos, directory, sh, batch-rename

I have a bunch of files within a directory structure as such:

```
Dir
    SubDir
            File
            File
    Subdir
            SubDir
                      File
            File
    File
```

Sorry for the messy formatting, but as you can see there are files at all different directory levels. All of these file names have a string of 7 numbers appended to them as such: 1234567_filename.ext. I am trying to remove the number and underscore at the start of the filename.

Right now I am using bash and using this oneliner to rename the files using mv and cut:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | cut -d_ -f2-10)"; done
```

This is being run while I am CD'd into the directory. I would love to find a way to do this recursively, so that it only renamed files, not folders. I have also used a foreach loop in the shell, outside of bash for directories that have a bunch of folders with files in them and no other subdirectories as such:

```
foreach$ set p=`echo $f | cut -d/ -f1`
foreach$ set n=`echo $f | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d_ -f2-10`
foreach$ mv $f $p/$n
foreach$ end
```

But that only works when there are no other subdirectories within the folders.

Is there a loop or oneliner I can use to rename all files within the directories? I even tried using `find` but couldn't figure out how to incorporate `cut` into the code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You want to remove the number and `_` ?

Comment: Shoot, yes sorry, was just about to edit the post to clarify that.

Comment: `set` is not used to set ordinary variables, and `end` is not a `bash` keyword.

Comment: The `foreach` loop was used outside of bash in just a regular shell.

Comment: How about a small tweak to what you have:   for i in ``find .``; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | cut -d_ -f2-10)"; done.    Basically, replace your * with ``find . ``.  Ugh, can't figure out how to print backticks, going just add this as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` does provide functions, and these can be recursive, but you don't need a recursive function for this job.  You just need to enumerate all the files in the tree.  The `find` command can do that, but turning on `bash`'s `globstar` option and using a shell glob to do it is safer:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

# enumerate all the files in the tree rooted at the current working directory
for f in **; do
    # ignore directories
    test -d "$f" && continue

    # separate the base file name from the path
    name=$(basename "$f")
    dir=$(dirname "$f")

    # perform the rename, using a pattern substitution on the name part
    mv "$f" "${dir}/${name/#???????_/}"
done
```

Note that that does not verify that file names actually match the pattern you specified before performing the rename; I'm taking you at your word that they do.  If such a check were wanted then it could certainly be added.

Comment: This looks like the winner. Thanks everyone for your help, but this one worked the best for me.  If I wanted to modify this to remove spaces and replace with underscores from all full file paths would I do something like this:

`mv "$f" "${dir/ /_/}/${name/ /_/}"`

Comment: This looks like a heavier-weight version of the solution posted at the bottom of my answer. Do you really need to use the external tools `basename` and `dirname` when you have parameter expansion? What about excluding filenames like `abcdefg_abcd.ext`, i.e. without numbers?

Comment: @VanCityGuy - no, you probably wouldn't do that...  If you try to `mv "foo bar/baz" "foo_bar/baz"`, and the target directory doesn't already exist, the mv will fail.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl‘s rename (standalone command):

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's|/[0-9]{7}_([^/]+$)|/$1|' **/*
```

If everything looks fine remove `-n`.

> `globstar`: If set, the pattern ** used in  a  pathname  expansion  context  will
>                         match  all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If
>                         the pattern is followed by a /, only directories  and  subdirectories
>                         match.

Comment: @Inian: Thank you. I've updated my answer and fixed a bug. It became more complicated to prevent renaming directories.

Comment: I tried this one and it threw up an error saying the -n option was not valid for `rename`. I am using bash 4.2 in a mac osx terminal shell. Perhaps it is not compatible. I should have given more info. But thank you for all of the effort!

Comment: @VanCityGuy: I assume you're not using Perl‘s rename implementation [This](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050630022203488) might help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this small tweak to what you have already:

```
for i in `find . -type f`; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | cut -d_ -f2-10)"; done
```

Basically just swapping the * with `find . -type f`

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible to do this using `find`...

```
find -E . -type f \
  -regex '.*/[0-9]{7}_.*\.txt' \
  -exec sh -c 'f="${0#*/}"; mv -v "$0" "${0%/*}/${f#*_}"' {} \;
```

Your `find` options may be different -- I'm doing this in FreeBSD.  The idea here is:

- `-E` instructs `find` to use extended regular expressions.
- `-type f` causes only normal files (not directories or symlinks) to be found.
- `-regex ...` matches the files you're looking for. You can make this more specific if you need to.
- `exec ... \;` runs a command, using `{}` (the file we've found) as an argument.

The command we're running uses parameter expansion first to grab the target directory and second to strip the filename. Note the temporary variable `$f`, which is used to address the possibility of extra underscores being part of the filename.

Note that this is NOT a `bash` command, though you can of course run it from the bash shell. If you want a bash solution that does not require use of an external tool like `find`, you may be able to do the following:

```
$ shopt -s extglob   # use extended glob format
$ shopt -s globstar  # recurse using "**"
$ for f in **/+([0-9])_*.txt; do f="./$f"; echo mv "$f" "${f%/*}/${f##*_}"; done
```

This uses the same logic as the `find` solution, but uses bash v4 `extglob` to provide better filename matching and `globstar` to recurse through subdirectories.

Hope these help.